# Why does class B<T> not see a protected member of parent class A<T>?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code fails to compile ([ideone](http://ideone.com/x57lBH)):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(T* t) : t_(t) {}

protected:
    T* t_;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B(T* t) : A<T>(t) {}

    T get() { return *t_; }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    B<int> b(&i);
    std::cout << b.get() << std::endl;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
prog.cpp:17:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 't_'
        T get() { return *t_; }
                          ^
```

By my understanding, `B<T>` should have access to protected members of its parent class. Why does `B<T>` not see the protected member `A<T>::t_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the base class `A<T>` is dependent on tempalate parameter `T`, then is a dependent base class, and `t_` is a nondependent name, which is not looked up in dependent base class.

You can make `t_` dependent to solve the issue, e.g.

```
T get() { return *this->t_; }
```

or

```
T get() { return *A<T>::t_; }
```

or

```
T get() { 
    using A<T>::t_;
    return *t_; 
}
```